# Line bundles on Grassmannians $Gr(m, n)$ and $Gr(n-m, n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, grassmannian

Let $Gr=Gr(m, V)$ be a Grassmannian of $m$-dimensional vector subspaces in the $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. There is a Plücker embedding $p_1: Gr \hookrightarrow \mathbb P(\Lambda^m V)$ mapping an $m$-dimensional vector subspace $U \subset V$ to the point $p_1(U)=\mathbb P(\Lambda^m U)$. It gives a series of line bundles $p_1^* \mathcal O(k)$. One can prove that they are the only line bundles on $Gr$, thus $Pic(Gr)=\mathbb Z$.

But there is another way to see $Gr$: as $Gr(n-m, V^*)$, replacing $U \subset V$ by $\ker(V^* \to U^*) \subset V^*)$. It gives another Plücker embedding $p_2: Gr \hookrightarrow \mathbb P(\Lambda^{n-m} V^*)$ and another series $p_2^* \mathcal O(l)$ of line bundles. But Picard group is the same.

So what $p_2^* \mathcal O(l)$ corresponds to $p_1^* \mathcal O(k)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ell = k$.

The two projective spaces are also isomorphic (given a choice of volume form on $V$) and the diagram commutes.

Comment: @Matt I think he just means a choice of nonzero element in $\bigwedge^n V$.

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear. The natural map $\bigwedge^m V \otimes \bigwedge^{n-m}V \to \bigwedge^n V$ becomes a perfect pairing once we identify $\bigwedge^nV \cong \mathbb{C}$.